# Смена значения всех полей с одним id

Tags: javascript

Есть много текстовых полей с одним id. Нужно, чтобы сразу на все поля распространялось событие при клике. На деле меняется только одно поле. Как охватить все поля с одинаковым `id`?

Comment: > Есть много текстовых полей с одним id.

Дальше можно не читать. Используйте class-ы или name-ы.

Comment: а зачем вам много полей с одним id? Id является уникальным идентификатором и не должен повторяться

Comment: Понял, так не работает

<img src="bold.gif" onclick="click_bb('.smallt', 'b');" />
<textarea class='smallt'></textarea>

Comment: за такой код в аду для программистов заготовлен отдельный котел с кипящим скипидаром. Вынесите обработчики в отдельный файл или секцию скриптов, не нужно запихивать их в тэги. Более того, может, я что-то забыл, но с чего бы это обычная строка '.smallt' должна интерпретироваться как последовательность элементов DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, вы хотите что то, типа такого реализовать http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/2sahv93t/

**HTML**:

```
<input class='inp'>
<input class='inp'>
<input class='inp'>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$('.inp').click(function () {
    $('.inp').each(function () {
       this.value = 'text';
    });
})
```

Comment: Верно, но не помогло

Comment: а что не получилось коль не секрет?

Comment: Функция не выполняется

    <img src="bold.gif" onclick="click_bb('.smallt', 'b');" />
    <textarea class='smallt'></textarea>

Comment: инлайн-обработчики это зло! отдельные файлы со скриптами, отдельные для стилей и т.д.